# Creating a CSS block from an object using JSON stringify?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working solving how to export to string an object and indent everything properly and I believe that if I use JSON.stringify that might get me most of the way there.

Here is an small example of the idea.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
// create object with the correct indentation 
var styleBlock = {[
   {
      "<style>" : "display: block"
   },
   {
      "</style>":""
   }
]}

var result = JSON.stringify(styleBlock, null, 3);

// desired result 

<style>
   display: block;
</style>
```

If I can create that object and then export the correct indentation I would still need to get rid of the quotes around the strings and values.

What I expect from stringify is this:

```
// undesired result 

{
   "<style>" : {
       "display: block;"
   }
}
{
   "</style>"
}
```

AWS services had a bit more complex JSON syntax that included types.

I can't get the code above to compile in typescript so I don't know if this would work.

The alternative I am looking into is the same as the HTMLElement approach. A type with leaves and branches.

Comment: Your styleBlock isn't valid. It's an array wrapped in curlies. Why does it need to be an object? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @ray trying to export a heirarchical data much like XML and CSS and indent it properly

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` can pretty print like `JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 2)`. Note the **`<pre>`** element.

```js
let ugly = {"items":[{"address":"someemail1@yahoo.com","code":"554","error":"554 delivery error: dd This user doesn't have a yahoo.com account (someemail1@yahoo.com) [0] - mta1481.mail.ne1.yahoo.com","created_at":"Thu, 07 May 2015 23:07:47 UTC"},{"address":"someemail3@domain.com","code":"550","error":"550 No Such User Here","created_at":"Thu, 02 Jul 2015 17:01:31 UTC"},{"address":"someemail4@domain.com","code":"550","error":"550 Administrative prohibition","created_at":"Thu, 21 May 2015 03:30:38 UTC"}]};

document.querySelector("pre").appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(ugly, null, 2)));
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```